# Why is a to `Any` casted `String` object no more considered as String (while the other way round it is)?

Tags: scala, types

When casting a String to the type `Any`, it will no more be considered automatically as `String` -- why ? See the following example:

```
val str = "foo"
val strAsAny = "bar".asInstanceOf[Any]
def f1(x: String) = println(x.toString)
def f2(x: Any) = println(x.toString)

f1(str) // works, type exactly given
f2(str) // works, subtype of Any given

f1(strAsAny) // works not, but strAsAny.isInstanceOf[String] = true !
f2(strAsAny) // works, type exactly given
```

This confuses me a bit, because both values do still have the type `String` :

```
scala> str.isInstanceOf[String]
res4: Boolean = true

scala> strAsAny.isInstanceOf[String]
res5: Boolean = true
```

My guess is, that only type conversions "to get upwards" of the interhitance-chain will be done automatically. Is this correct ?

Comment: Do not confuse the **type of the object** (run-time information) and the **type of an expression** (compile-time information). An object is what it is (which is why both `isInstanceOf` are true); the type of an expression, however, is the "view" for which operations are allowed (e.g. determined to be valid/type-safe) by the compile-time environment/type-checker. Thus the *type of the compile-time expressions* ensure that the object is only used "as the correct type" during run-time, but not not actually affect the *type of the object*. (This is a little lie with magic coercions.)

Comment: @pst This is exactly what did confuse me, thank you for your explanation. Do you know a source, where I can read more about these kinds of type-checks ? Perhaps in 'Programming in Scala' or the SLS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflating *static types* with *dynamic types*.

A static type is what *the compiler knows*, and is something that exists *at compile time*.

That is, when you do this:

```
val strAsAny = "bar".asInstanceOf[Any]
```

Then the compiler will know (or think) that `strAsAny` has type `Any`. It won't know there's a `String` stored in there.

Mind you, avoid as much as possible `asInstanceOf`, since most valid uses of it can be replaced by type ascription (`"bar" : Any`) or pattern matching (`case anyAsStr: String => "got a String"`), both of which are *safe*. The operator `asInstanceOf` is *not* safe, because it tells the compiler to ignore what it knows, and believe what you are telling it, even when it knows it's wrong.

So, `asInstanceOf` is mostly a compile-time operator, though it also produces some code for the JVM to execute.

Now, what the compiler thinks matter because it only let you call methods it knows can be called. So even though, *at run time*, `strAsAny` will contain a `String`, the compiler *doesn't know that*. You told it to forget that `"bar"` is a `String`, and it did so. Therefore, you are not allowed to call `String` methods on it.

On the other hand, a dynamic type is *what is true at run time*. In most cases, for a language like Scala, the compiler has no way of knowing what will be true or not at run time.

And whether the compiler can know something or not, `isInstanceOf` is a *run time operation*. The compiler doesn't have anything to say about what will happen.

So, when you do this:

```
strAsAny.isInstanceOf[String]
```

The compiler doesn't care -- it just compiles the code. When you *execute* the code, then the JVM will verify what kind of value is stored inside `strAsAny`, and verify that it is, indeed, a `String`, and then return `true`.

Answer (score 5):

Types specify what you expect, not what you've actually got.  You can place anything that satisfies what you expect into that slot.

With `Any`, you expect very little, so anything works.  With `String`, you expect `length`, `charAt`, etc..  So a `String` can satisfy the requirements of an `Any` but not vice versa.  If you happen to put a `String` into an `Any` slot, you are now only promising to do what `Any` can, so you can't take that value and give it to something expecting a `String`.

This is called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and is a fundamental principle of (safe) object-oriented design.

Comment: Thank you. But something still confuses me: Even if `strAsAny` still has type `String`, the method `f1` does not look at this type ? But whay does method `f2` look at the other types of `str`, since `str` is assigned to `String` and not to `Any` ? Why the different treatment ?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood - There is no different treatment.  `f2` says "I want anything that gives me what an `Any` can deliver".  `str` can deliver that: `String` is a subclass of `Any`.  `f1` wants what `String` can deliver, and `str` can deliver that.  However, `strAsAny` can delivery what `Any` can deliver but _that is all it promises_.  You have specifically told it to only promise that much.  So when `f1` asks for more it complains that you've promised it too little with `strAsAny`.  The compiler isn't going to help you here: you've _explicitly made it promise less_.

Comment: Thank you. So the only thing the method look at is the type the object is assigned to (in case of `strAsAny` it is `Any`) and not the types the object has (in case of `strAsAny` the types are the same as of `str`) ?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood - Yes, more or less.  The method looks at the type that _you say that the object is_.  If you tell it less than you could ("it's an `Any`!" when it is a `String`) or if you lie to it ("it's a `List[Int]`!" when it is a `String`), it will act according to what you tell it.  (If you've lied to it, this may later result in an exception when it tries to use something that isn't what it is claimed to be.  Merely being less specific is safe, however.)